Why is everything helm super slow?
Helm for me is unbearably slow. I'm not sure how to diagnose it.
If I either try helm-M-x or helm-buffers-list, it takes like 5 seconds to show any result.
I will try to fill out more details here, but after searching, it seems it's a known problem; I just haven't found a solution.

"... it's a known problem" - where? Why don't you provide a link? And have you profiled the slow response?
